# How does Firefox generate the hash values when installing extensions

Tags: firefox, hash, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, sha

I wrote some code that manually takes a XPI that was already installed from one Firefox profile, and set's up the xpi to be manually set up on a different profile or computer entirely.

So the I set everything up fine within the extensions.sqlite Database that is within the user profile folder. I can even rename the extension on the fly when I move the xpi itself into the extension folder.

Here's my question: When I extract the XPI, there is a file called 'harness-options.json'. Within that file there are two variables, docsSHA256 and jsSHA256.

These to hash variables must be based on the extension in some way, but I am not sure how exactly.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how firefox generates these hash codes?

Thanks.

Comment: I found that the jsSHA256 is created using the "main.js" file of the extension.

I still can't find the other SHA though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not generate these hashes at all. It is the Add-on SDK which does. The Firefox extension manager does not care about `harness-options.json` at all. The SDK loader in turn, does care about `harness-options.json` a bit, but doesn't do anything with `jsSHA256` or `docsSHA256` at the moment. Other tools, such as the validator that runs when you upload something to addons.mozilla.org, do care about `jsSHA256` at least.

It should be noted that add-ons not using the SDK do not (normally) contain a `harness-options.json` file at all.

There will be one `jsSHA256` per module `lib/`, e.g. one for `main.js` and so on.

`docsSHA256` for `main.js` will be generated from `README.md` when the SDK builds the XPI. Apparantly, `README.md` is not packed into the XPI. For all other modules it appears `docsSHA256` appears to be null.

The code in question lives in [`manifest.py`](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/d506602d7a01f89f4b372bbd0c9e260340ebc596/python-lib/cuddlefish/manifest.py).

In the end you shouldn't mess with the XPI (other than repacking an unpacked extension) and/or `extensions.sqlite` at all. Especially the latter isn't meant to be modified externally.
Just drop the your XPIs files in the corresponding `extensions/` folder of the profile and the Add-on manager will automatically pick them up the next time you start the browser.

Comment: It does automatically add the extensions, but it also puts a big "WARNING, ACTIVATE THIS EXTENSION".

As I don't want that to happen, I am forced to manually add everything to the sqlite DB.

I did figure out that the docsSHA256 was basically taking the hash of an empty file.

The thing is, those hashes are going to end being used by Firefox when they follow in Chromes footsteps and make all extension HAVE to be hosted on their addon site.

In the mean time, I'll be staying one step ahead of them in that regard.

Comment: There is no indication at all that Mozilla might follow in Chrome's footsteps and create a walled-addon-garden. I don't know where you got that idea... That would violate their (our) [manifesto](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/manifesto/) not to speak of the wrath they would incur from the community.

Comment: What I don't understand is why they even ask to activate anything. Anyone with malicious intent can easily by-pass any security features short of making add-ons work like chromes soon will.

That's why I think they will make addons closed off.

How will they compete with chrome when chrome will be incredibly more secure compared to Firefox?

Comment: As you already said yourself: If you're on the system already and malicious all bets are off anyway, also for Chrome. Chrome isn't any more or less secure because of their "feature". The Firefox warning was built to deter drive-by installations of (system-wide) add-ons that aren't malicious but crap anyway, such as all those nice toolbars that get installed with other software. Not abiding the [Add-on Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_guidelines) can indeed land you on the blacklist.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being annoying, but I really enjoy discussions about application security.
What good will the Blocklist do if it is only based on the application Id?

Comment: And would you look at this, not a month later and Firefox changed how extensions get validated and added a mysterious new sqlite database called webappsstore.sqlite

Comment: `webappstore.sqlite` is [not exactly new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data) and not exactly [mysterious](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=webappsstore). And there were no changes yet to extensions, although there was a recent proposal for what was called a File Registry, if you refer to that. That proposal has some opposition, incl. myself. The proposal was withdrawn again (for the moment) because "there are some concerns that we need to revise and see what can be done to address them".

Comment: They now store extension information in a json instead of a sqlite DB.

Now what would make them do that?

Comment: Plain and simple: performance. Second: easy usage and maintainability. The usual number of installed extensions makes it faster to read/write a single json file (off the main thread) than to deal with the overhead of SQLite, especially when you don't really need sophisticated relational queries.